# Handling External DB without PK

Tags: sql-server

How can I handle a table given to me from an outside DB that does not have a PK? Or even an ID field that marks the record specifically. I am using SQL Server.

I have a table that has come to me that has information on an event. I need to be able to pull the company information that I can. There is an event_id field that I can use to keep track of the rows, but there is no company_id.

Here are the rows I think are useful for this discussion:

> event_id
>
> company_name

I can do a grouping by company_name and get multiple counts, so I know the name is consistent. The end goal of this is to connect this to my larger DB that DOES have company_id columns.

The external DB is not willing to change their export at all.

Should I create a separate key table for the companies in this table and simply keep my own set of keys? Is that good practice? If so, how can I do that? If not, what should I consider doing?

Forgive me if this question has been answered before. I looked but could not find it. I'm not even sure how to word this question. I would love to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the external company is not willing to correct their export, then you can set up your own lookup table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Companies
(
  CompanyID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  CompanyName nvarchar(255)
);
```

Now, when you get a new import, I assume this goes into some temporary ETL table. So you do:

```
INSERT dbo.Companies(CompanyName)
  SELECT company_name 
  FROM dbo.ETL_Table AS etl
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM dbo.Companies 
      WHERE CompanyName = etl.company_name
  )
  GROUP BY company_name;
```

Now you can join against your lookup table on the name, and that join can produce the IDs you need to use in your own referential integrity.

**This does not handle the case when a company name changes, and I don't know how you can detect that.**

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.